# Highcharts: how to clean up failed range selector button press?

Tags: javascript, button, highcharts, zooming

I have a Highcharts plot with a range selector. From time to time, i saw this issue

[image]

My intention was to press "2w" while "1m" button was pressed previously. But the press somehow was not done. The result was as shown in the figure. The "1m" button still pressed and the "2w" button was highlighted already. This is not desired. How to fix this issue? Thanks!

Here is my code

```
rangeSelector:{
    enabled:true,
    inputEnabled:false,
    buttonSpacing: 1,
    buttonTheme: {
        fill: 'none',
        stroke: 'none',
        r: 5,
        style: {
            color: "black",
            fontSize: '13px',
        }
    },
    labelStyle: {
        color: '#a8a8a8',
        fontSize: '10px'
    },
    buttons: [{
        type: 'week',
        count: 2,
        text: '2w'
    }, {
        type: 'month',
        count: 1,
        text: '1m'
    }, {
        type: 'month',
        count: 6,
        text: '6m'
    }, {
        type: 'ytd',
        text: 'YTD'
    }, {
        type: 'year',
        count: 1,
        text: '1y'
    }]
}
```

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: I threw your code into a Highstocks example here: http://jsfiddle.net/765SF/ and it looks like it's working... Maybe you should post the rest of your code in a fiddle?

Comment: What I want probably is disabling the hover effect. So unless the button pressed, no effect should be shown.

Comment: Have you tried to set hover states like here http://jsfiddle.net/s6R8Y/

Comment: Yes, tried. The example does show the hover effect. I want to disable it.

Comment: Set hover enabled to false not working. See http://jsfiddle.net/marsant/s6R8Y/1/

Comment: You can disable it by setting fill as null http://jsfiddle.net/J82wz/

Comment: Yes, worked! Thanks, Sebastian!